# How to disable HTML attributes with js?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I have a menu with hover dropdown menus. On mobile I want to disable the `href` attribute so that clicking the link doesn't redirect, but opens the dropdown. I am currently using `removeAttribute()` to do that. But the problem is that if the user uses the site in a smaller window which triggers the mobile version and then makes the window bigger I need to add back the `href`. I could use `setAttribute()` but then I have to keep track of the links to add them back and I don't feel like that's the best solution. Is there a way to just disable the `href` attribute with js?

Comment: `<a>` tags shouldn't really be used as buttons. you should use a `<button>` when you want to show the drop down, and a `<a>` when you want it to redirect. would you mind showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prevent default action only on smaller screens.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var menuLink = document.getElementById('dropdownMenuLink'); // The menu link ID

    menuLink.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        // Check if the viewport width is less than or equal to 768px (Adjust to your use case)
        if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
            // Prevent default link action
            event.preventDefault();
            // Display an alert
            alert('Dropdown opening...'); // Placeholder action
            // Here you would toggle your dropdown or execute any other mobile-specific action
        }
        // On larger screens, the default action (navigation) proceeds
    });
});
```

```html
<a href="#" class="menu-link" id="dropdownMenuLink">Menu Link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor for a screen resize with this event...

```
window.visualViewport.onresize=function(e){

 // And set conditions based on its height and/or width like this...

 if(this.offsetWidth < 800){                // Or use offsetHeight.

   a.href='javascript:SomeFunction();';     // If small make the href call a JS function.

 } else {

   a.href='https://somesite.com/';         // If big make it redirect to some url.

 }

};
```

**NB:**  *a.href* is just a pseudo-code example… in real life you’ll have to specify which anchor by ID or some other way.

Comment: That's the problem. I could do that but then I have to memorize all the links in an array or something. It can get messy with multilevel dropdowns, which is why I don't wanna use it.